# create multiple edges having vertex id number 0 to 49

Tags: gremlin

This can be a bit problem occuring for me as i am working for more time than needed . Can you tell me can i add an edge between two vertices and here i have 50 vertices and i cant find a way to add edge on it having vertex id 0 to 49 . Till now I have use

```
gremlin> (0..<50)each{g.addEdge(V[it],V[it+1]).next()}
No such property: V for class: groovysh_evaluate
gremlin> (0..<=49)each{g.addEdge(g.getVertex([NodeID]),g.getVertex([NodeID+1]),'abc')}
groovysh_parse: 2: unexpected token: = @ line 2, column 6.
   (0..<=49)each{g.addEdge(g.getVertex([NodeID]),g.getVertex([NodeID+1]),'abc')}
        ^

1 error
```

Comment: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want to iterate through the vertices and add an edge from one vertex to the next until they are all connected. First, I'll create the 50 vertices:

```
gremlin> g.inject((0..<50).toArray()).as('i').addV('myid',select('i')).iterate()
```

Then I'll add the edges:

```
gremlin> (0..<49).each { def v = g.V().has('myid',(long) it).next(); v.addEdge('knows',g.V().has('myid',(long)it+1).next()) }
```

I cast to "long" in my example above as I was using a TinkerGraph. That cast may not be necessary for dynamo. Note that you can combine all of this into a single line with:

```
gremlin> g.addV().repeat(__.as('a').addV().as('b').
                            select(last,'a','b').
                            addE('.').from('a').to('b').
                            inV().as('a')).
                  times(49)
```

The above will create both the vertices and the edges at the same time in an iterative fashion. Note that "49" represents the number of edges you'd like to have.

You have spread this same question across multiple tags in StackOverflow including: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925515/create-gremlin-graph-error-store-in-local-dynamodb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929626/error-in-graph-creation-gremlin-in-titandb-used-in-local-dynamodb). In all cases you have lots of basic syntax errors and are calling methods that don't exist and referencing objects that don't exist. I suggest you focus on more of the basics of Java and Groovy before digging too deeply into dynamodb and TinkerPop. At a mimimum, start with the TinkerPop tutorials (like the one mentioned in the comment to your question) to get a better feel for the APIs and how the programmign syntax.

Comment: I think this is answer is not for tinkerpopup 3 i am using titandb as backend used in local dynamodb command written in gremlin server

Comment: So How this learning process be fullfill as to know  going deep into before digging too deeply into dynamodb and TinkerPop

Comment: This is a TinkerPop 3 answer. The Gremlin used for a TinkerGraph is the same as the Gremlin used for Titan which is the same as the Gremlin for Neo4j. That's the entire point of TinkerPop - it is graph database agnostic. It also doesn't matter if you are using Gremlin Server. The code I wrote will work just fine there as well. There might be some problems between TinkerPop versions - you didn't say what version of Titan you were using - but the first two traversals that answer the core of your question should work (I have some doubts about the third traversal for it's use of `Pop.last`).

Comment: If there is a problem with the first two lines - just say what they are and provide some details. As to your second question about the "learning process", I'm merely suggesting you slow down. TinkerPop, Gremlin server, Titan, and Dynamo is a lot to learn at once especially if you are also learning the details of java/groovy along the way. Start with just TinkerGraph and the Gremlin Console. Read the TinkerPop tutorials. Get comfortable and confident. Then move on to Titan. All the Gremlin you wrote for TinkerGraph should also work for Titan (again taking versions into account).

Comment: Titan.version() = 1.0.0

 Gremlin.version() = 3.0.1-incubating                                &   TinkerPop 3

Comment: U are write but i want to just experiment by performance tuning on it using creation of graph in a parent child relationship manner having 1 parent and 2 child and from that 2 child make it a parent and produce 2 child from that and by continuing loop upto 1000k vertex and therir connected edges and we want to get the traversal time Can u help me to solve out this problem....!   Thanks in advance