# Adding multiple vertices, changing one property-value (tinkerpop3 + python GLV)

Tags: python, loops, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinpython

I'm trying to size down my code, but I need several instances of data of this type:

```
g.addV('A').property('a-type','thing-x').property('a-value',1).next()
g.addV('A').property('a-type','thing-x').property('a-value',2).next()
...   
g.addV('A').property('a-type','thing-x').property('a-value',n).next()
```

Up to 'a-value' being n (for instance 50).

```
# I tried a version of a loop I found here 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907529/create-multiple-edges-having-vertex-id-number-0-to-49
# 
g.inject((0..<50).toArray()).as('i').addV('a-value',select('i')).iterate()
```

But I get an error:

```
g.inject((0..<50).toArray()).as('i').addV('a-value',select('i')).iterate()
             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

EDIT: Having tried to build upon the answer, I'd just like to add that for my case, calling `t.iterate()` within the for-loop gives the expected result, but not so if this is called outside of the loop, as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you found was being used inside the Gremlin console and hence using Groovy constructs. From Python you would do something like:

```
for i in range(1,51):
    g.addV('test').property('mykey',i).iterate()
```

However that will add the vertices one at a time so would be better to write them in small batches in a way similar to this.

```
t = g.addV('test').property('mykey',1)
for i in range(2,51):
    t.addV('test').property('mykey',i)
t.iterate()
```

Comment: Many thanks, this worked! Still getting used to the different usage between python and gremlin.

Comment: Would there be an elegant way of adding edges between the adjacent nodes - e.g. between 2 and 1 and 3, but not between 2 and 4, and so on. I can create a separate question as well of course.

Comment: Keeping the vertex and edge IDs in a list and iterating over it adding the edges in batches would work as one simple solution.